# Find a matrix given its 5th power

Tags: matrices

Find a matrix $B$ such that $B^{5}$ is equal to $\begin{bmatrix}
20 & 12\\
19 & 13\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

I have tried this using the $2\times2$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and multiplying it by itself $5$ times but that has left me with polynomials of very high degrees. Any hints on how to start this?

Comment: How about computing the determinant of $B$ given the determinant of $B^5$? That gives you a constraint to work with. Not sure if that really helps though. Can't help but think that this involves diagonalisation...

Comment: so det(B)=ad-cb is equal to $det(B^{5})$?

Comment: No. The determinant is a homomorphism, so $\det(B^5) = \det(B)^5$.

Comment: It gives me that $ad-cb$=2 which is a nice constraint but still doesn't help me solve I don't think.

Answer (score 4):

The eigenvalues of your matrix are $32$ and $1$. The vector $(1,1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $32$, whereas the vector $(-12,19)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. So, let$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&-12\\1&19\end{bmatrix}.$$Then$$P^{-1}.B^5.P=\begin{bmatrix}32&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$So, take$$B=P.\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{50}{31}&\frac{12}{31}\\\frac{19}{31}&\frac{43}{31}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic polynomial is 
$$
(x-20)(x-13)-12\times 19 = x^2 - 33x +260 - 240 + 12= x^2 -33x + 32 = (x-32)(x-1),
$$
so $B^5$ is diagonalizable. Solve $(B^5 - 32I) x = 0$ gives a solution $(1,1)^{\mathrm T}$, and  solve $(B^5 - I)x = 0$ gives a solution $(12, -19)^{\mathrm T}$, so there exists a matrix 
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 12 \\ 1 & -19
\end{bmatrix}
$$
such that 
$$
P^{-1}B^5 P = \mathrm {diag}(32,1). 
$$
So we could take $B = P\mathrm {diag} (2, 1)P^{-1}$.